# How to receive Multipart Form Data in GET Call Retrofit Android Kotlin

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I am POSTING my data which has a string and a file to the backend using retrofit Multipart to my spring boot backend. It is working properly and it's storing the data in my tables.

I want to retrieve the data from DB and I have created an API in spring boot to send Multipart data but I am unable to find a way to parse the multipart data in retrofit GET API.

For my project, I need to create a user profile so for that, I need to send user data and his profile picture. Currently, I am using multipart form data to send the data as parts, and rather than sending user details I am sending user details as JSON string and then converting it to the model in spring boot and for file, I am using a multipart file like below

```
ResponseEntity<String> saveUser(@RequestParam("user") String stringUserRequest,
                                @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file);
```

The posting is working properly but now I want to retrieve the data the same way I had posted. How to do that?

Also, is there a better way to save and retrieve user data with his profile picture than what I am doing? I want to know for retrofit and spring boot as that is what I am using for my project.

Comment: Have a look at the code for an email client as a client will receive mails multi parted.

Comment: But it is much simpler to do two requests. One for json text and one for the picture. But... you could also put the picture in the json and then use a json parser. That would be the common way.

Comment: I want to know how its actually done in other apps like Facebook, Instagram LinkedIn, etc
Like is it fine to do 2 requests will it be considered a wrong practice architecturally?

Comment: Also which code are you talking about could you send a link for the same

Comment: Could you give any link with regards to putting the picture in json method

Comment: You can encode the picture to a base64 string. And that string you put in the json like you do normally with your other string values.

Comment: But I had read that base64 takes a lot of space so is that the right way to do?

Comment: Yes it takes 30% more bytes. But profile pictures are mostly small. Or make them small. And use jpg's. So just try.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

Comment: Images is working
Now I want to send videos and file how should I send them as bas64 string only?

Comment: Why would you send them base64 encoded? Makes no sense. 30% more traffic.

Comment: Then how to send videos and files to my backend? You had suggested base64 for images so I continued with that.
I want to know the correct way to handle files as it is getting very messy in coding.

Comment: should I just upload files to some storage like firebase or aws and store the url in my db or what?

Comment: I suggested base64 for images during download together with other data as you only wanted to do one request. And i only suggested base64 because a profile image is mostly very small. I never talked about base64 for uploading. Dont use base64 for uploading video files.

Comment: I understood about not using base64 for others.
I want to know then how should I deal with files in android. How should I upload them? Where should I store it? What is the correct way of handling any type of file in general?

Comment: You upload files just as they are. Just the bytes of the file. Where you wanna upload your files to (in other words: where you wanna store them) is up to you. If you mean by 'handling' uploading then the correct way is to transfer the bytes of the file.

Comment: ok understood instead of sending base64 string I will send byte array is that correct?

Comment: Dont put the bytes of the video file first in a byte array. That takes a lot of memory. Memory ploblems garanted. Just write the bytes of the file in a loop to the outputstream of the connection. Then you only need a small buffer of say 8192 bytes only.

Comment: Can I create one API to save multipart files in my backend and call that from the frontend and send it as multipart and after saving the file I will send data so 2 calls
Is this a correct method todo?

Comment: I dont know what backend you have. And you can create only API's for it if you coded that backend yourself already. Further i dont understand what you want. Too vague. Not exact.

Comment: I will explain properly as It's been a long time and I am not getting any solid answer to this.

I have to make an application somewhat similar to LinkedIn so I need a profile picture, posted images, files, and videos same as LinkedIn has or Facebook has.

Now my backend is made using Java Spring Boot and the frontend is Android Kotlin.

My question is how do I send so many files from the frontend to the backend. What is the correct way to do that by which I mean that how does facebook or linkedin handle these type of files and how do they store it.

Hope this clarifies

Comment: I dont know how facebook or linkedin handle their business.